# Run python script with supervisord

Tags: python, discord, supervisord

I have a simple python script ([discord bot](https://github.com/maksymov/afi)) and it works well when I run it with command `python3 discord_bot.py &` or `sh start_bot.sh`.
But how can I run it with supervisord?

Update:
I have installed supervisord. But when I try to run process, I have error:

```
exit status 0; not expected
```

My supervisord config:

```
[program:AFI]
command=/home/maksymov/www/Bots/discord_bots/afi/start_bot.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/afi.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/afi.out.log
user=www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use one of the "supervisors". Like system.d or [ramona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ramona)

The first one is more general. The second is more "python-specific"

Comment: I believe you can

Answer (score 1):

I guess your program tries to run as a daemon. I pasted the most relevant part from documentation:

[Supervisord subprocess](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html)

Programs meant to be run under supervisor **should not daemonize themselves**. Instead, they should run in the foreground. They should not detach from the terminal from which they are started.

The easiest way to tell if a program will run in the foreground is to run the command that invokes the program from a shell prompt. If it gives you control of the terminal back, but continues running, it’s daemonizing itself and that will almost certainly be the wrong way to run it under supervisor.